# How do you determine the current Python egg cache directory?

Tags: python

I'm aware that you can override the egg cache directory with the environment variable PYTHON_EGG_CACHE, and that you can look that override up in os.envrion. It looks like the default for Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 16 is **/.cache/Python-Eggs**.

How would you log the location of the egg cache when there is no PYTHON_EGG_CACHE provided in the environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PYTHON_EGG_CACHE` envvar is used by setuptools to determine the location to store installed egg packages. (You can read more about setuptools [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools))

Taking a look through the current code for setuptools on [github](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/master/pkg_resources/__init__.py) (In the function currently named `get_default_cache`) shows that if the lookup of the envvar fails, a default is calculated using the following:

```
from pkg_resources.extern import appdirs

return (
    os.environ.get('PYTHON_EGG_CACHE')
    or appdirs.user_cache_dir(appname='Python-Eggs')
)
```

[appdirs](https://pypi.org/project/appdirs/) is a pretty simple python lib that gets standard file system locations. the `user_cache_dir` logic depends on your OS, and has quite a few conditionals (Far too much to explain here, but if you are interested, the [logic is on github](https://github.com/ActiveState/appdirs/blob/master/appdirs.py#L265))

Since you mentioned U16 - the logic there is:

- Look up another envvar (`XDG_CACHE_HOME`), and then append `/Python-Eggs` (For example, if `XDG_CACHE_HOME` is `/tmp/xdg/` then the `/tmp/xdg/Python-Eggs` is used)
- If the second envvar is not defined, then `~/.cache/Python-Eggs` is used.